# How to prevent ServiceStack EventLogFactory from logging DEBUG events?

Tags: c#, error-handling, servicestack

The EventLogFactory is writing Information logs for every DEBUG statement from OrmLite or Redis, simply from this one line of code:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new EventLogFactory("MyApplication");
```

For example:

```
An error occurred in the application: MyApplication
Exception: DEBUG: SELECT "Id", "Name" FROM "MyTable"

An error occurred in the application: MyApplication
Exception: DEBUG: S: GET urn:iauthsession:upuuVGyYt48yoMYjdaBB
```

This service handles thousands of Redis operations per minute, so logging all these is cumbersome.

This happens even if I do not add any ServiceExceptionHandlers or UncaughtExceptionHandlers; I do not have any of my own logging code active.

I saw that the EventLogFactory sets its IsDebugEnabled flag to true, but I couldn't find any relevant place that it is referenced in the source. Nonetheless, I tried adding this (redundant) line, to no effect:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = false });
```

How do I prevent these DEBUG logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just modified the `EventLogFactory` constructor to accept a `debugEnabled:false` property which will prevent logging debug messages with:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new EventLogFactory("MyApplication", debugEnabled:false);
```

This change is available from v4.0.41+ of ServiceStack that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks in advance, but right now the MyGet feed is missing the main ServiceStack package. :)

Comment: @FacioRatio hmm apologies, just re-published the latest packages to MyGet.

Comment: No worries. Your patch is much appreciated! Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Event Log does not offer much control over logging.

However, if you were willing to switch to NLog it's pretty trivial. You just need to add a rule to the config to set the minimum level to Info:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the NLog suggestion. I will prototype it as part of a larger logging initiative in the near future.